# autohotkey disable a key globally but enable in a window

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I wanna disable a key globally, say it, <kbd>space</kbd>,
but enable in a specific window, eg, `Notepad`.

Then I put below lines in `key.ahk` and load it

```
space::return

#IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad
    space::send {space}
#IfWinActive
```

But below error occurs when I type <kbd>space</kbd> in `Notepad`:

> 71 hotkeys have been received in last 1109 ms.
>   Do you want to continue?
>   (see #MaxHotkeysPerInterval in the help file)

seems like result in infinite recursion.

If I change

```
    space::send {space}
```

to

```
    space::space
```

Then nothing happens when <kbd>space</kbd> is typed in `Notepad`.

The question is, how can I disable <kbd>space</kbd> globally, but enable it in `Notepad`?

**== EDIT ==**

I *do* want to disable the key *globally*, or more usefully, remap to another key-sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to worry about what to do when Notepad is not active.  If you only have a portion that deals with what happens when Notepad **is** active, then the non-active times will just do nothing by default.

This code will disable <kbd>Space</kbd> in everything except Notepad, as described in your question:

```
space::
    if WinActive("ahk_class Notepad") 
    {
        send {Asc 32}
        return
    }
```

The `send {Asc 32}` line sends the ASCII code for a space, which prevents the script from catching it's own sent space and starting over.

Comment: Thx for your answer. But I *do* want to disable the key globally, or more usefully, remap to another key-sequence.

Comment: @qeatzy My code does disable the space key globally, unless Notepad is the active window. If you want another key sequence globally, just follow this with an `else ` statement containing those commands.

Comment: Thx, just tried it, but strangely a <kbd>Return</kbd> is sent instead of <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Comment: correction: it send `space`, but followed by `return`.

Comment: Thx, fixed by adding `return` command at the last.

Comment: @qeatzy Not sure how that would happen, unless you had other code in that file too.  I have only the code I posted in my file and it works fine for me.  I was just about to suggest adding the `return` statement when you posted your last comment. :)

Comment: yeah, seems like indeed caused by other code in the file if not end with `return` command.

Answer (score 1):

The code for the accepted answer (as it is listed at the time of this writing) has a return inside of the `if` statement...

```
space::
    if WinActive("ahk_class Notepad") 
    {
        send {Asc 32}
        return
    }
```

Best practice would be to put the `return` outside of the if statement (place a return at the end of any hotkey code), so it will always return, so if this code block is used in another file and/or with other code, execution won't continue past the routine that handles the `space::` hotkey.

Currently, any subsequent code will still execute if space is pressed on a-non notepad window.

The slight modification to correct this would be as follows:

```
space::
    if WinActive("ahk_class Notepad") 
    {
        send {Asc 32}
    }
return
```

If the `return` statement is outside of the `if` statement, you can also get rid of the brackets for the single `send` line following the if statement:

```
space::
    if WinActive("ahk_class Notepad") 
        send {Asc 32}
return
```

One more slight variation on this would be to simply return if Notepad is not active.  This can be useful in cases where there is a bunch of following code (instead of just a single `send` statement), basically because it can be easier to read and understand...

```
space::
    if !WinActive("ahk_class Notepad") 
        return   ; execution will end here unless Notepad is active

    send {Asc 32}

    ...

    ...

    ; lots of other code can be added here 
    ; without encompassing it in an if {} block

    ...

    ...

return   ; make sure nothing following this will execute
```